# Url redirect for both local and internet to web service in asp.net using flex

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, proxy, redirect

How do I so this please?

A flex swf file uses the following actionscript to access the db server while embedded within an asp.net web application (3.5). The Db Server and the Asp.Net app are all on the same web server... ie..(1) machine, (1) domain..

```
<mx:WebService id="WsChartBTS"
        wsdl="https://domain.net/WService.asmx?WSDL"
        showBusyCursor="true"
        fault="WsFaultChart(event)">
        <mx:operation name="GetWService"
            result="Result(event)"
            fault="WSEvent(event)">
            <mx:request>
                <Ticker>{Tick}</Ticker>
                <Range>{Rng}</Range>
            </mx:request>
        </mx:operation>
</mx:WebService>
```

Problem:  When I move from production (web) to test (localhost) I have to change the URL in the above Flex Actionscript to get the test data to display... (This is crazy!!)...

Then I have to recompile...

Question:  How do I create a Simple URL Redirect to use either:

localhost/WService.asmx?WSDL or

http://webdomain.net/WServices.asmx?WSDL

depending on where the web server is deployed...?

This is a simple proxy server or URL redirect of some sort, but I am not sure how to create it.. I can code in C# and I can code in Actionscript, Intermediate level.

Any help as in detailed explanation would be greatly appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your local development environment is identical, in directory structure, to the production environment, Use relative URLs, like this:

```
<mx:WebService id="WsChartBTS"
        wsdl="/WService.asmx?WSDL"
        showBusyCursor="true"
        fault="WsFaultChart(event)">
        <mx:operation name="GetWService"
            result="Result(event)"
            fault="WSEvent(event)">
            <mx:request>
                <Ticker>{Tick}</Ticker>
                <Range>{Rng}</Range>
            </mx:request>
        </mx:operation>
</mx:WebService>
```

You could also move the service URL into an external config file which you load at runtime and then use the values to set the wsdl value on your WebService component.

Comment: Well what do you know? It works great! I think VS2005 had some sort of weird debug (local) web server issue that prevented me from doing this.. but now that've upgraded this is not a problem. THANKS!!!!